# LCD randomly goes one character further in the ascii table

Tags: lcd

Here's my code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
int rs = 11;
int rw = 10;
int en = 9;
int d0 = 1;
int d1 = 2;
int d2 = 3;
int d3 = 4;
int d4 = 5;
int d5 = 6;
int d6 = 7;
int d7 = 8;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, rw, en, d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(4800);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Loading...");
  delay(3000);
  lcd.setCursor(1,1);
  lcd.print("waht");
}

void loop() {

}
```

And here's the output:
[image]

Also note the first line of text starts in the second column. I've tried with a different LCD and the same issue occurs. It seems to go one character further in ascii (ex: the '**.**'s become '**/**') if that's any clue to what's going on. In a separate program (exact same setup) I can print "Hello World" on the first line no problem. Anyone know why it's doing this and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Looks like it gets one or two least significant bits wrong. So check wiring and so

Comment: Btw, Arduino pins 0 and 1 are wired to USB serial (on many boards) - so you can try it without Serial.begin and if it works, just move pin(s) to not use arduino pin 1

Answer (score 2):

Your Least Significant Bit is always 1 (Check the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) to see this).
You might have a problem with your wiring, double check the pin you use and that the continuity is good.

Also, as [KIIV](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/23841/kiiv) said in comment, depending on the board you use, you might have a conflict with the serial port (Which pull the line high when not transmitting, explaining the result you get). Try moving pin 1 to another one.